# How to download an artifact from maven repository

Tags: android, gradle, build.gradle

I'm developing a Native-Module for my React-Native application let's call it MyModule.
I want to add android library to MyModule. The owner of the library provided me with the url and the credentials:

```
maven {
            url 'url'
            credentials {
                username 'username'
                password 'password'
            }
        }
```

The owner said to add it under my **project's** `build.gradle`.
Do I need to add it under the root project (which will use MyModule) `gradle` or in MyModule's gradle?
I tried to add it under `repositories` in MyModule's `gradle` but I keep getting an error:

```
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> Could not resolve all task dependencies for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
   > Could not find any matches for ******* as no versions of ******* are available.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - file:/Users/**/Workspace/***/**/***/node_modules/react-native/android/**/**/**/maven-metadata.xml
       - file:/Users/****/Workspace/***/***/***/node_modules/jsc-android/dist/com/***/***/maven-metadata.xml
       - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/***/***/maven-metadata.xml
       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/***/****/maven-metadata.xml
       - https://maven.google.com/com/****/***/maven-metadata.xml
       - https://www.jitpack.io/com/***/****/maven-metadata.xml
       - https://jitpack.io/com/****/***/maven-metadata.xml
       - https://dl.anagog.com/android/public/com/***/****/maven-metadata.xml
     Required by:
         project :app > project :my-module-react-native

Possible solution:
 - Declare repository providing the artifact, see the documentation at https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/declaring_repositories.html
```

What is the right place to add this url so that it could download it?

Answer (score 0):

If you need an access to private artifact repository you have to define it in your module (MyModule) like following ([Documentation](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/declaring_repositories.html#sub:accessing_secured_ivy_repositories)):

```
repositories {
  maven {
    url = uri("link")
    credentials {
      username = "user"
      password = "password"
    }
  }
}
```

So repositories have to be defined in each of the modules. You can also define it on the root level but within `allprojects{}` or `subprojects{}` blocks as they will apply to all modules.
Similar to this code of [mapbox](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-navigation-android/blob/main/build.gradle#L51)

And if you properly configured your repository it should be listed below the line saying: "Searched in the following locations:"

If this repo is in the list and still your dependency doesn't get resolved double check your dependency coordinates, dependency might be wrong or some other misconfiguration on the repository side.

Comment: Please note that using `allprojects{}` and `subprojects{}` blocks is [discouraged](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/sharing_build_logic_between_subprojects.html#sec:convention_plugins_vs_cross_configuration); instead you should use [Convention Plugins](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/sharing_build_logic_between_subprojects.html#sec:convention_plugins).

Comment: Heads up will take a note in my projects that those configurations are discouraged, while for simple build scripts creating a plugin seems to be an overkill and is used in different contexts need to be extended and teams just blindly rely on plugins. Just want to say that you shouldn't immediately create a plugin. If you need this in 5 different places with exact same functionality then maybe.